# Copy worksheet with specified name to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This macro copies Excel worksheets that have a numeric name to another Excel workbook.
For example only worksheets that are titled with 6 digits. For Example "140655".

I want to also copy over the worksheets that have a standard English name such as "Budget".

```vb
Const CalcDelay = 0.00000578704

Dim CopyRange As String
Dim PasteRange As String
Dim ScanFileOpen As Byte
Dim ScanCount As Byte
Dim ScanSaveSpec As String
Dim ScanSaveFile As String
Dim ReturnWindow As String
Dim ReportFile As String
Dim ExcelVersion As String

Sub OpenReportFile()
ReturnWindow = [ProcessWinSpec].Value

If [ReportFileFlag].Value = True Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=[ReportFileSpec].Value
    Windows(ReturnWindow).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Else
    MsgBox ("Error: File not found")
End If

End Sub


Sub DoScan()
Dim Work As Variant
Dim X As Interger

ReturnWindow = [ProcessWinSpec].Value
ReportFile = [ReportFileName].Value

ExcelVersion = IIf([FileNameExt].Value = ".xls", 2003, 2013)

For Each Work In [ScanFlags]

    ScanFileOpen = 0
    ScanCount = 0

    If Work.Value = 1 Then

        [ScanName].Value = Work.Offset(0, 1).Value
        [ScanCalcRange].Calculate
        ScanSaveFile = [ScanFile].Value
        ScanSaveSpec = [ScanSpec].Value

        For X = Work.Offset(0, 2).Value To 1 Step -1
            ScanTabName = Work.Offset(0, X + 2).Value
            [ScanTab].Value = ScanTabName
            [ScanCalcRange].Calculate
            If [ReadFlag].Value = 1 Then DoCopyTab
        Next
    End If
    If ScanFileOpen = 1 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWindow.Close
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to make those changes yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code in the form of a [mre], and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. If you're unable to make that effort, hire a contractor to make them for you.

Comment: If difficult to see how your posted code relates to the description, particularly with the over-use of square brackets

Comment: @KenWhite there's code and the author is explaining what is not clear to accomplish.  I agree it's a weak question, but the it is reproducable in that it's not clear how to scan for words in a file?

Comment: @pgSystemTester: It's a dump of code the OP got from copy/pasting from somewhere and a requirement specification. It's not any different than the homework question that posts an empty  C `main()` stub and asks how to change it to actually complete a task. This one just posted someone else's code and asks us to customize it for them.

Comment: @KenWhite yea I suppose you're right. Still, it's better than some efforts, but I agree with you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your question on how to execute a macro if files have a certain name, probably the best approach would be to create an array of words, and then loop through them seeking a match. See example with your code:

```
Sub OpenReportFile()
    Const yourWords = "budget,actual,accept" '<--- fill these in separated by comman
    ReturnWindow = [ProcessWinSpec].Value
    Dim foundMatch As Boolean
    
    If [ReportFileFlag].Value = True Then
        foundMatch = True
    Else
        
        Dim wordArray() As String, i As Long
        wordArray = Split(yourWords, ",")
        
        'loopS through words
        For i = LBound(wordArray) To UBound(wordArray)
            If UCase(wordArray(i)) = UCase([ReportFileFlag].Value) Then
                foundMatch = True
                Exit For 'exits loop after match
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
    If foundMatch Then
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=[ReportFileSpec].Value
      Windows(ReturnWindow).Activate
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
        MsgBox ("Error: File not found")
    End If

End Sub
```